# Correct pronunciation of "和"

Tags: pronunciation

I know when it comes to names, it's pronounced "he" in "何", but my question is what about the regular:

> 我和你

I think it should be "han" in "漢", but some people say "he", so my question is what is the correct way to pronounce.

Comment: You'll hear hàn in Taiwan, but hé virtually everywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"han" is the informal pronunciation of 和 in Taiwan.
In mainland China nobody pronunces it as "han"

Answer (score 1):

I only heard some folks from Taipei have said 我han4你 to mean 我和(he2)你.

In standard mandarin, 和 is pronounced as he2.